# Php update checkbox states in db

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am new in php, i have a question.
How can I update checkbox states in db? checkboxes have same name. when click on update button it will update all row checkboxes stat in db. and checkboxes in db  get true or false

html part

```
<div class='blocks-output'>
    <form action='/admin/blocks' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='updated_block_index' value=''/>
        <input type='hidden' name='updated_block_name' value=''/>
        <table class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr class='text-uppercase'>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>selected</td>
                    <td>block index</td>
                    <td>block name</td>
                    <td>edit</td>
                    <td>delete</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($blocksInfo as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' <?php if($row['selected'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><?php echo $row['block_index']; ?></p>

                            <div class='form-group hidea'>
                                <input type='number' class='form-control' name='block_index' placeholder='Block index' value='<?php echo $row['block_index']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><?php echo $row['block_name']; ?></p>

                            <div class='form-group hidea'>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='block_name' placeholder='Block name' value='<?php echo $row['block_name']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href='' class='edit-row btn btn-primary' role='button'>edit</a>
                            <button class='update-row btn btn-primary' name='update_row' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>update</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='delete_row' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='clear_table' value='delete all'>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td ></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='update_table' value='update'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

thank you :)

Comment: you get array , whats the problem ?

Comment: i just don't know how to do that

Comment: change the checkbox name='id' to name='id[]' and get the checkbox in array value..

Comment: use name='id[]' insted of name='id' for your checkboxes,then you will get an array of selected values on submit.Update the table using that

Comment: what is exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Replace 'id' for the name to below.

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' <?php if($row['selected'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> />
```

When you declared Name='id' all the elements have been picking on the same name, after the above declaration, each checkbox will have a unique name equal to the ID.

Comment: good answer.....everyone is saying that keep id array i don't know why they are saying even they have unique id value...anyways nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here that a few simple google searches won't answer.
You could start with this:

- [Getting checkbox values on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit)

and work your way from there

Comment: I am searching but not found anything that i want

Answer (score 0):

That's simple something like this:
form.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
<label class="checkbox inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="frm_update" id="frm_update" value="<?=$id>"> check this box
</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['frm_update'])){
  //do what you wanted to do. Save it to database etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array like: `id[]` and each checkbox should be given value like their ID in table.

So it will be in short  `<input type="checkbox" name='id[]' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' <?php if($row['selected'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> />`

So after post You will get only checkboxes which were checked , so accordingly save data in DB.