# How can i post the checkbox with php?

Tags: php, html

This is my form and categories comes from the database with while loop.
I want to insert the checked inputs only in to database.

How can i detect which checkbox is selected ?

```
<form action="account.php" method="POST">
    <ul class="account-info">
        <li>Category1 : <input type="checkbox" value="val1" name="cat1"></li>
        <li>Category2 : <input type="checkbox" value="val2" name="cat1"></li>
        <li>Category3 : <input type="checkbox" value="val3" name="cat1"></li>
        <!-- while continues -->
        <li>Category100 : <input type="checkbox" value="val100" name="cat1"></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Only selected checkboxes are passed in the POST array.

Comment: you might be thinking of a radio button.  (because you ask which ONE is selected, and named them all cat1).  What you have in your code are checkboxes, and each one needs a unique name, and then you can check each one in php when the form is posted.

Comment: @RightClick They don't need to be uniquely named, check my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting checkbox values on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit)

Comment: @JayBlanchard its okey but i dont know how to detect checked inputs. Generally im using it :  `$String = $_POST["postedstring"];` But im getting checkboxes from database with while loop. how can i get these values in account.php

Comment: I would like to suggest removing the tags: `php`, `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` (and maybe also `html5`). This is basic html (form posting). You can test this by creating a pure html form and checking what URL the browser triggers when you hit "submit".

Comment: @Styphon thanks for reminding me of that, I forgot you could do that because I usually care which one was clicked.  I guess if you have all distinct values and don't care which checkbox they came from that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `account.php` only the check boxes will be posted. As you've named them all the same though, only 1 will be posted, the last checkbox. If you want them to have the same name and come through as an array you need to add `[]` after the name, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="val100" name="cat1[]">
```

Then in your `account.php` where they are submitted you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST['cat1'] as $val)
{
    echo "$val<br>";
}
```

That will echo out the values of all the checked boxes.

Comment: Its okey but cat2 ? or cat75 i dont know how many categories will be added.

Comment: @sonerkaya using the `[]` will generate and array of only the checked boxes. so if they check cat2 and cat75, only those 2 will be added to the array. so using a foreach loop it will loop twice allowing you to use only those 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like that: 
This code will check which categories are activated 
assuming that your database returns categories from 0 to x

```
 $i = 0; 
    while(true){
    if ($_POST["cat".$i."]) {   
        //category activated
    } 
    else { 
        //no category found -> loop ends
        break;
    }
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Its okey but cat2 ? or cat75 i dont know how many categories will be added. I cant write codes manually because categories comes from database

Answer (score 0):

change the `name="cat1"` to `name="cat[1][]"`

in your `account.php` page

```
foreach($_POST['cat'] as $category){ 
    foreach($category as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its okey but cat2 ? or cat75 i dont know how many categories will be added. I cant write codes manually because categories comes from database

Comment: then you want to do this `cat[1][]` for the name

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have your options set up as if they were radio buttons all having the same name turning into 1 value out of the 3 possible. If you want them to be conventional checkboxes you have to give them separate names.

in your PHP you would check if the `array_key_exists` for the checkbox name in question, this is how I usually translate the checkbox fields in a form to be easier to use:

```
<?php
    $checked = array(
        'cat1' => array_key_exists('cat1', $_POST),
        'cat2' => array_key_exists('cat2', $_POST),
        'cat3' => array_key_exists('cat3', $_POST)
    );
    print_r($checked);
    exit;
?>
```