# mysql php jquery hide show select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, hide, show

I know a little bit of PHP programming, but none of JQuery. 
I have build a `<select>` dropdown menu with data from MySql db.
But now I want a button or something next to the `<select>` option, like a + sign or something that will give me a extra `<select>` option. And that this can come as many time as you want.

Ps. I'm sorry for my English.

Here is a picture of how I want this to be.

[image]

and then next you will get this.
[image]
And here is the code what I already have made.

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database') 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select id, name from table");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unset($id, $name);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name']; 
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';         
    }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: what is your purpose of showing multiple select box?

Comment: I want that people can select more then 1 city.

Comment: Simple Use check box for this.Problem solved :)

Comment: The easiest way would be to use something like [Bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **check box** instead of **dropdown** for multiple selection

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id, $name);//use if you want
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name']; 

    echo '<input name="city[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$name.'" />'.$name;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for a couple of cities... Imagine how it would looks like with hundreds of cities :-)

Comment: yes you made me thinking @artur filipak.Any idea to help to implement this?

Comment: @mujas Thank you, I will be using your answer! But how can I sent a selected checkbox along with a contact form?

Comment: @artur filipiak Thanks for your answer, actually your answer is the solution to my question. But it is just for a few cities.

Comment: please check this answer for form submit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit

Comment: Please check this answer for jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit

Comment: @mujas Thanks, but this is just from a HTML form. How do I sent the data that comes from a database..?

Comment: To which php file you want to send this value

Comment: @mujas it will be a contact form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112610/discussion-between-mujas-and-jaesen).