# How to save loop-generated data in a variable

Tags: php

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I am using php code to fetch checked box values,
how can I save each checked values in different variable out of loop?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['box'])){

        foreach($_POST['box'] as $selected){
            echo $selected."</br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where and why you save it depends upon what you want to do with it later!

Comment: Because i have to pass theme on mail function

Comment: So use POST data itself, why to create so many variables?

Comment: @Anant now thats an inteligent suggestion at last

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['box']))` use `isset()` for checkboxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting checkbox values on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit)

Comment: The point @Fred-ii- is making is that UNCHECKED checkboxes are not actually passed to the PHP script, so you should not assume that any of them are actually in $_POST

Comment: @Anant through that method i just get the last selected value not all,i have tried that one.

Comment: @Anant Nope; it should get the values from the selected checked inputs. Edit: unless they pass a key value.

Comment: When PHP fills and gives you $_POST its all yours. Why do people thinks they must move $_POST values into other locations. Use $_POST as it is, its all yours to do with as you like. You can even add to it, for the suration of the script you are running

Comment: @Anant ONLY if the checkbox is checked, so it could be completely MISSING from $_POST if non of the checkboxes are checked

Comment: @Tauqeer  please make yourself clear by some expected outcome? that will help you and us.At-least i am not clear about what you are trying to achieve (meanwhile in conversation it's confusing to me)