# how to send by mail values of multiple checkboxes with php

Tags: php, forms

I do not succeed in sending the values of multiple checkboxes from a form with PHP mail.

This is piece of my form with the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="registercheckbox[]" value="saturday-16:00">
<input type="checkbox" name="registercheckbox[]" value="saturday-17:00">
<input type="checkbox" name="registercheckbox[]" value="saturday-18:00">
```

In my php file i use this to settle the values form the multiple checkboxes:

```
$selected_checkbox = $_POST['registercheckbox'];

  if(empty($selected_checkbox)) {
    echo("you have to chose at least 1 checkbox!");
  }
  else {

    $N = count($selected_checkbox);
    echo('Your preferences are: ');
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $preferences = $selected_checkbox[$i];
      echo($selected_checkbox[$i] . " ");

    }

  }
```

In the body preparing for the email i use this:

```
  $body .= "Preferences: ";
  $body .= $preferences;
  $body .= "\n";
```

and to send the mail:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

The echoes are working fine: it echoes every selected value of the checkboxes
But sending the email: it only sends the last checked checkbox value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You overwrite it each time, try: `$preferences .= $selected_checkbox[$i];`

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't be concatenating `$body` like that; it's quite problemsome.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit) will help you. A `foreach` would work best for this. It's probably also a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you just store on $preferences the last value, so you could use`implode` on `$selected_checkbox` and get a list comma-separated so:

```
$body .= "Preferences: ";
$body .= implode(', ', $selected_checkbox);
$body .= "\n";
```

Comment: works perfect now!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a foreach loop?

```
if(empty($selected_checkbox)) {
  echo("you have to chose at least 1 checkbox!");
} else {
  $preferences = ''; // avoid php info messages.

  foreach($selected_checkbox as $value){
    $preferences .= $value . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

And the change to your code is to append the next line of text, you're currently overwriting it with `$preferences = 'new value'` each loop cycle.

The short hand is: `$preferences .= 'new value'`, otherwise interpreted as `$preferences = $preferences . 'new value';`