# Get the Name value in php and how to fetch it using post

Tags: php

How to get the `Name` value using `Post` method in php like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $categoryTitle;?>">
```

How to Post the `Name` value..?

```
<?php $name=$_POST[''] ?>
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $categoryTitle;?>"

Comment: Do `<?php $name = $_POST[$categoryTitle] ?>` ?

Comment: for each $_POST

Answer (score 0):

So this is your input :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $categoryTitle;?>">
```

When you submit your form using `POST` method, you can access your input value using the name of each input like this : `$value_of_field = $_POST['input_name'];`

So if the `name` of your input is `<?php echo $categoryTitle;?>`, you can get the value of this input using : `<?php $name = $_POST[$categoryTitle] ?>`

If you want information about how to get checkbox value on submit, this other question / anwser may help you : [Getting checkbox values on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit)