# Retrieve dynamically generate check box array values in controller

Tags: laravel-5

in my html i can able to add more fields using jquery and the field am generating is check box array. i need to retrieve this in my controller.

so far i have tried

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="washing[]"  id="washing[]">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="dryclean[]" id="dryclean[]">
```

In controller

```
 $clothtypeid = $request->input('clothtypeid');
 $washing = $request->input('washing');
 $pressing = $request->input('pressing');

 for($i=0;$i<count($clothtypeid);$i++){
   //in here how to test if the checkbox is ticked then value=1 else 0 ??
 }



I expect if the checkbox is ticked then i have to make 1 else 0
Thanks in Advance
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did a bit of digging and found this [Tutorial](https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/) which suggests;

- Setting the input type to "checkbox" like you did there..
- Keep the same name and include the '[]' at the end of the name attribute so that you have the following in your form;

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="washing">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="dryclean">
  ```

Then in the controller you can get the value by doing the following;

```
if(!empty($request['check_list'])){
 // Loop through array to get the checked values.
  foreach($request['check_list'] as $item){
  //do something here like;
    if($item == 'washing'){ //make db operation or assign to a variable..}
    else if($item == 'dryclean'){//make db operation}
  }
}
```

This is a very basic example as you can see and I have to say that I haven't tested it yet but I believe it will work. Try it and give feedback.

EDIT: There is an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421988/getting-checkbox-values-on-submit)

Comment: i appreciate your reply.i already found the answer.
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="addmore[0][washing]"  id="washing"> 
in controller
 $addmore = $request->input('addmore');
       $maxkey = max(array_keys($addmore));

       for($i=0; $i<= $maxkey; $i++){
 if(isset($addmore[$i]['washing']) && $addmore[$i]['washing'] === "1"){ 
                         $newwash = 1; 
                    } else { 
                         $newwash = 0;
                    }
}

Comment: glad you found a solution :)